# Do GWT CEllTables have a 15 row limit?

Tags: gwt, row, limit

I have a little piece of code which populates a CellTable from a
Type  by adding the table as a DataProviders DataDisplay and by
using the DataProviders list to create a ColumnSortHandler and
corresponding Comparators...  so each time the user clicks next I
populate the table in this manner with the next set of data.  It all
works great apart from when the number of elements in my set of data
is greater than 15.  In this case only the top 15 (ordered) elements
are displayed I.E. only 15 rows of the CellTable are visible within
the VerticalDialog.  Is this a default somewhere or can I configure
this row limit.  I've looked around my code and I can see places where
I have instantiated a list and this will default to 10 elements but 15
has me baffled.

I can provide code but thought this would jog a memory without the
need for boring old code.

Many thanks

Tony

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a default yes: [http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/CellTable.html#CellTable()](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/CellTable.html#CellTable%28%29)

> Constructs a table with a default page size of 15.

You can change it at any time with `setPageSize` or `setVisibleRange`.

Comment: Wow and thanks and sorry for the lack of research on my part. I actually enjoy the 15 rows thing for my particular implementation, as my data get sorted not the table contents so if the user drives changes to the values in my data then the table reflects the re-ordering and the missing elements promote themselves to being listed within the table. Kinda nice for me but made me curious at to where this 15 came from. Thanks @Thomas :)

Answer (score 0):

Adding to [Thomas Broyer answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5522268/439171). I always use the code below passing my `CellTables`/`CellLists` when I don't want pagination.

```
public static void setupOnePageList(final AbstractHasData<?> cellTable) {
    cellTable.addRowCountChangeHandler(new RowCountChangeEvent.Handler() {
        @Override
        public void onRowCountChange(RowCountChangeEvent event) {
            cellTable.setVisibleRange(new Range(0, event.getNewRowCount()));
        }
    });
}
```